# How to use deferred by function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to load the same page 6 times with different parameter at the same time, and do something after all pages be loaded, jQuery deferred function can do that, the easiest way is.

```
$.when(
        $.post('ajax1.php', {val: 1}),
        $.post('ajax2.php', {val: 2}),
        $.post('ajax3.php', {val: 3}),
        $.post('ajax4.php', {val: 4}),
        $.post('ajax5.php', {val: 5}),
        $.post('ajax6.php', {val: 6})

    )
    .done(function() {
        console.log('all done');
    });
```

But it's really looks not smart at all, I want to load by function, and use for loop for the repeat work.

```
var done = $.Deferred();

$.when(loadPage(done))
    .done(function() {
        console.log("all done");
    });

function loadPage(done) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        $.post("ajax.php", {val: i} function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    return done.resolve();
}
```

But I don't know how to return resolve() after six pages all done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.when` to achieve the same

```
loadPage(done).done(function(){
    console.log("all done");
})

function loadPage() {
    var requests = [],
        xhr;
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        xhr = $.post("ajax.php", {
            val: i
        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
        requests.push(xhr)
    }

    return $.when.apply($, requests)
}
```